# Apache2, PHP5, and Interbase/Firebird on Windows 2003/XP

Tags: php, command-line, firebird, interbase

I have recently upgraded from Apache 1.26 and PHP 4.3 to 2.2.11 and 5.2.9 respectively. With my original setup I had a scheduled task set to run every Sunday for a weekly newsletter. It would connect to my database (Interbase/Firebird) to find out what events were opening for the following week and get the list of addresses the email will be sent to. Of course, I had to change how PHP the task was setup since command line execution has changed slightly from version 4 to 5. Once that was fixed the real problem reared it's head.

Now when executing any script from the command line I cannot connect to my database. I receive the following error from `ibase_errmsg`: Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". Failed to locate host machice. Undefined service gds_db/tcp.

The same script works perfectly from the browser. Also, the database connect code is used all through my site for logging in, getting records, and updating records.

If anyone has any idea why a script will not connect to the database when executed from the command line, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the post everyone. I have answered that question. I had to copy my fbclient.dll file in to my PHP folder and rename it gds32.dll.

Does anyone know why I had to do this for executing command line scripts only, and not for scripts that run in the browser?